# Modal Dialog Box working with Mozilla but Not working with Chrome

Tags: javascript

Hi All
I am trying to use modal dialog box in my code. like

window.showModalDialog('pageurl');

Ideally when a modal dialog box is open one should not be able to go to parent window until it is closed.

it is working fine with Mozilla. But in Chrome the one can take control to parent window even if it is open.

Can anyone tell why the problem is occuring? And please help me solving this problem. I t is necessary for me to show same type of modal dialog box in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.showModalDialog(''pageurl);
```

Can not really be "modal" with Chrome, it's just made like this.

You have to implement your own modal box using JavaScript / JQuery
[Example Demo](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html)

Comment: But in this demo, i am able to bring my control to parent window. Dialog box disappears then.      My requirement is parent window should not get until until i respond  to box

Comment: Search for JQuery modal window on Google and you should find what you need. I linked the first one i found

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you step away from `showModalDialog` and use a **LightBox** variant. That gives you more control over what you want and is more XB (cross browser).

Comment: Can you please help with a link?